# Running code before front-end instance is terminated

Tags: google-app-engine

How can I run a piece of code just before a GAE front-end instance is terminated?

I am looking at running code in Servlet.destroy(), but does this actually get called before the instance is pulled offline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [LifecycleManager](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/LifecycleManager) class to register a shutdown hook for your Java runtime:

```
LifecycleManager.getInstance().setShutdownHook( new ShutdownHook()
{
    @Override
    public void shutdown()
    {
        // do your stuff here
    }
} );
```

You can use the [ServletContextListener](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Using_a_ServletContextListener) to add a startup hook for your servlet and put the code above in the `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)` method.

From the documentation about the ServerContextListener in the link above, it appears that at the moment, AppEngine does not invoke the `contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event)` method when the instance is shutting down.